# Parameters are sent inappropriate to facebook pixel from google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

We use Google Tag Manager to send custom events and parameters to Facebook. We also have a data layer implemented. Now we are trying to get the values from data layer via DataLayer Variables. The problem is that values got successfully out of the data layer in a debug mode. But Facebook Pixel checker tool shows not the values sent, but a code fragment:

```
fbq("trackCustom","my_custom_event",{value:google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXXXX"].macro(5).
```

Here is my code snippet for custom event:

```
<script>
  fbq('trackCustom', 'Passenger', {
    value:{{DataLayer Price}},
    currency: 'USD'
      });
</script>

This is our DataLayer code:

'[
  {
    "gtm.start": XXXXXXXXXXX,
    "event": "gtm.js",
    "gtm.uniqueEventId": 0
  },
  {
    "gtm.start": XXXXXXXXXXX,
    "event": "gtm.js",
    "gtm.uniqueEventId": 6
  },
  {
    "event": "checkout",
    "ecommerce":     {
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "checkout":       {
        "products":         [
          {
            "name": "XXXXXX",
            "id": "84",
            "price": "55",
            "category": "XXXXXXX",
            "quantity": "X"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "gtm.uniqueEventId": 7
  },
  {
    "event": "gtm.dom",
    "gtm.uniqueEventId": 11
  },
  {
    "event": "gtm.load",
    "gtm.uniqueEventId": 14
  }
]'
```

Can u please recommend what should I do so that facebook got values but not a code fragment?

Comment: Hi @Konstantin Vashkevich I think you didnt add your variable correctly into your FB- Custom HTML tag. Make sure you dont add the ' '

Comment: @M.Kooi thanks for your reply! I found the reason why it didn't work: actually I set incorrect tag triggering order. I sent parameters before dataLayer formed the data.